# How to characterize all sets with Lebesgue-Borel measure of zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know that the Lebesgue-Borel measure (L-B-measure) on $\mathcal B^d$ with $d \in \mathbb N$ of a point in $\mathbb R^d$ is $0$, also clear that the L-B-measure of a countable set of points is $0$, but there might be other more complex sets in $\mathcal B^d$ which have the L-B-measure of zero.

Is it possible in some general way to describe what sets have $0$ L-B-measure?

Comment: What is L-B measure? How is it different from choosing *either* the Lebesgue *or* the Borel and sticking to it? [If you can show the two separately give the same collection of sets, suggest rephrasing the question in terms of just one of the two measures.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could go back to the definition to describe sets with zero measure.

A set $A$ in $\Bbb R^d$ with $d\in\Bbb N$ has zero measure if and only if for every real $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite or countable open cover

$$A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$$

where each $I_k$ is a $d$-dimensional open interval in $\Bbb R^d$, and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} m(I_i)<\epsilon$$

where $m(I)$ is the usual simple definition of measure of an open interval. I.e.

$$m((a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)\times\cdots\times(a_d,b_d))=\prod_{i=1}^d(b_i-a_i)$$

More briefly, the infimum of all sums of the measures of the intervals in a finite or countable open cover of $A$ is zero.

Do you need something different from this?

Comment: i don't think you can restrict to  a finite set of open intervals. Can you , with d=1, cover the rationals with a finite set F of open intervals such that m(UF) is arbitrarily small?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and corrections. I messed up! Unfortunately, I had to do an errand just after posting and just got back to edit my answer. I believe my answer is now correct.

Comment: After your correction i changed my down vote to an up vote.

Comment: @user254665: Thanks for your up vote... and for your catching one of my mistakes and letting me know.

Comment: It reminds me  of a deep Q : A set $S$ is strongly measure $ 0$ iff whenever  $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ is a positive real sequence then  $S $ has a cover $C=\{ c_n : n \in N)$  where each $ c_n$ is an open INTERVAL with $ \mu (c_n)<x_n.$  The Q is whether a strongly measure zero set must be countable.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I was not aware of that definition of a set with zero measure, but the criterion seems straight forward. If I understand you correctly from $A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$ follows that $\lambda(A) \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda(I_i)<\epsilon, \forall \epsilon >0$ and from that follows that $\lambda(A) = 0$ where $\lambda$ is L-B-measure.

Comment: @RoryDaulton It is not clear though why the open cover should be built out of open intervals. Imagine if instead of open intervals we build the open cover out of any L-B-measurable sets, then the criterion would still work, would not it?

Comment: @SergeyZykov: The "definition" I used was not of measure zero but rather of the outer measure of any set, and a set has zero measure iff its outer measure is zero. Open intervals are used in the definition, I believe, to keep the definition simple. It also avoids circularity since at this point the full measure has not been defined. You could use any L-B measurable sets, since each of those sets has a countable cover of open intervals of "small size," and the union of a countable number of countable open intervals is still countable.

Answer (score 1):

The outer measure  $m^o(S)$ of a set $S$ is the $GLB$ of $m(U)$ over all open $ U$ such that $S\subset U$ ....DEF'N :  A set $S$ satisfies $m(S)=0$ iff $m^o(S)=0$ . Many uncountable sets have measure $0$. In one dimension the Cantor set $C$ has $m(C)=0$. I am talking about Lebesgue measure.